# nice logs with cypress-mochawesome-reporter and cypress-terminal-report

Tags: cypress, cypress-mochawesome-reporter, cypress-terminal-report

I am trying to have nice executions logs in HTML reports generated by [cypress-mochawesome-reporter](https://github.com/LironEr/cypress-mochawesome-reporter). I found that [cypress-terminal-report](https://github.com/archfz/cypress-terminal-report/) [integrates with it](https://github.com/archfz/cypress-terminal-report?tab=readme-ov-file#cypress-mochawesome-reporter).

So I did this in `e2e.ts`:

```
import "cypress-mochawesome-reporter/register"
afterEach(() => {
   cy.wait(50, { log: false }).then(() =>
      cy.addTestContext({
         title: "Execution log",
         value: Cypress.TerminalReport.getLogs("txt"),
      })
   )
})
const logsCollectorOptions = {
   collectTypes: ["cy:command", "cy:log"],
}
require("cypress-terminal-report/src/installLogsCollector")(logsCollectorOptions)
```

and this in `cypress.config.ts`, inside the `setupNodeEvents` code block:

```
         require("cypress-terminal-report/src/installLogsPrinter")(on)
         require("cypress-mochawesome-reporter/plugin")(on)
```

In the HTML report, the log lines look like this:

```
        cy:command (K): click
        cy:command (X): contains    Peter
```

The first line is a pass, the second is a fail. I would like to look them like this instead:

```
        cy:command (✔️): click
        cy:command (❌): contains    Peter
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid me, that was easy. Just replace the `value` line in the code above with:

```
         value: Cypress.TerminalReport.getLogs("txt")
            .replaceAll("(K): ", "(✔️): ")
            .replaceAll("(X): ", "(❌): "),
```

Alternatively, as a starting point to have somewhat more control over each log line:

```
value: Cypress.TerminalReport.getLogs().reduce((acc: string, log: Log) => acc + "\n" + format(log), ""),
```

with e.g.

```
function format(log: Log): string {
   const symbol = log.severity == "error" ? "❌" : "✔️"
   return symbol + " " + log.message
}
import { Log } from "cypress-terminal-report/src/installLogsCollector"
```